# Loop and count in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I try to get at least three responses from a total of 10 textboxes. And an alert will occur if the total number of responses is less than three. I also try to eliminate responses that are only spaces, so I use `return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'')` to get rid of spaces before and after the string.

What I need to do is first set a variable "count" to be 0. Next to detect whether there is at least one character in a specific textbox, and if so, add 1 to "count". Then do this for all 10 textboxes. After that, check whether "count" is greater than 2; if so, go to a next page; otherwise, an alert will occur.

But it didn't work.

Another question is, how can I avoid iterating the process for all 10 textboxes?

````
var count=0

 function myTrim(x) {
  return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}

var x1 =  document.getElementById("textbox1").value; 
  var t1 = myTrim("x1");
  var n1 = t1.length;

  if  (n1<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }

var x2 =  document.getElementById("textbox2").value; 
  var t2 = myTrim("x2");
  var n2 = t2.length;

  if  (n2<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }

var x3 =  document.getElementById("textbox3").value; 
  var t3 = myTrim("x3");
  var n3 = t3.length;

  if  (n3<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }
var x4 =  document.getElementById("textbox4").value; 
  var t4 = myTrim("x4");
  var n4 = t4.length;

  if  (n4<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }

var x5 =  document.getElementById("textbox5").value; 
  var t5 = myTrim("x5");
  var n5 = t5.length;

  if  (n5<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }
var x6 =  document.getElementById("textbox6").value; 
  var t6 = myTrim("x6");
  var n6 = t6.length;

  if  (n6<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }
var x7 =  document.getElementById("textbox7").value; 
  var t7 = myTrim("x7");
  var n7 = t7.length;

  if  (n7<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }

var x8 =  document.getElementById("textbox8").value; 
  var t8 = myTrim("x8");
  var n8 = t8.length;

  if  (n8<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }
var x9 =  document.getElementById("textbox9").value; 
  var t9 = myTrim("x9");
  var n9 = t9.length;

  if  (n9<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }
var x10 =  document.getElementById("textbox10").value; 
  var t10 = myTrim("x10");
  var n10 = t10.length;

  if  (n10<1){
    count=count+0
  } else{
    count=count+1
  }



function checknumber() {
    if (count < 3){
            alert("You must enter at least 3 responses before you can continue.");
        } else {
            location.href="https://www.kindpng.com/imgv/hxbmxi_symbol-thumbs-up-clip-art-vector-free-clipart/" ; // if selection made, go to next page
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Minor thing, but `.trim()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)) gets rid of whitespace at the start/end of a string, without you having to write your own regex.

Comment: `count=count+0` => but why?

Comment: Seriously, this should be a loop. The specific problem of this code is that `myTrim("x1")` should actually be `myTrim(x1)` (without quotation marks).

Comment: when you are calling `myTrim("x2")` you are not passing value of x2, but string constant "x2"

Comment: @DBS Thank you for pointing out the issue. I guess I was thinking about for some browsers they do not support the trim() method.

Comment: @raina77ow So I guess there is no need for stating that count=count+0 if the condition isn't met. Also, thank you for pointing out the problem of the quotation marks!

Comment: @crack_iT Thank you for pointing out this! I think you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screams for loops:

```
let count = 0;
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  const textBoxValue = document.getElementById('textbox' + i).value;
  if (textBoxValue.trim() !== '') count++;
}
```

With the code you have, not only the same lines are repeated 10 times (the only meaningful thing that changes there is textbox's ID), but also their values are not actually checked: with `myTrim('x2')` the parameter you pass inside your function is a literal string 'x2', not the value of x2 variable.

As a sidenote, always express your intent directly; if checking against an empty string, write that check as is. And yes, writing your own `trim` implementation is not really necessary.

---

In fact, you don't have to check all the textbox values:

```
function formHasAtLeast(requiredMinimum) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    const textBoxValue = document.getElementById('textbox' + i).value;
    if (textBoxValue.trim() !== '') count++;
    // this line will stop that iteration immediately, 
    // as there's no need to check for 4th, 5th etc. textbox
    if (count === requiredMinimum) return true; 
  }
  return false;
}

function checkForm() {
  const minAnswers = 3;
  if (formHasAtLeast(minAnswers)) {
    location.href = "YOUR URL";
  }
  else {
    alert(`You have to fill at least ${minAnswers} responses`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate the method "post" in the function "checkForm", because I also want to store the responses on the server and it seems that I can only do this using the post method.

Comment: It's not a good idea to have too many responsibilities in a single function. What you can do is _call_ that other function there - and proceed with redirect after it's finalized, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class selector, `Document.getElementsByClassName("text-box")`, first apply a common class to all such text boxes. Then loop over the results.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

You can access inputs by class name and work with result as an array:

```js
function calculate() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('value-container');
  const result = Array.from(elements).map(e => e.value).filter(v => !!v && !!v.toString().trim()).length;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `Count of fields with value: ${result}`;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="value-container" /><br/>
<input type="text" class="value-container" /><br/>
<input type="text" class="value-container" /><br/>
<input type="text" class="value-container" /><br/>

<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Get Result</button>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array